# how to read image file and store in memory as base64 string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, image, file, base64

i've read few articles on stackoverflow and on internet about this but i have not find suitable answer for me.

so here's the newbie question. i have some image files sitting on my local disk such as *.jpg, *.png, and *.gif. now i want to read these files as base64 encoded string. how can i do this in c++?

i've tried to open the file as binary and store it in std:string. but that didn't work due to zero byte in the data. can anyone suggest a solution?

thanks in advance.

Comment: base64 is probably not the best solution. Just use a char array (as opposed to a string)

Comment: Read the binary contents and store in an `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of an `std::string`. Are you sure you need to base64 encode it?

Comment: maybe this might be helpful http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html

Comment: praetorian, i am expecting base64 encoded string as input for some library i'm writing, and i am trying to test it by reading an image file on local disk and creating a base64 encoded string.

Comment: @Prod the base 64 code you have linked to uses string concatenation for the results, ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[j]], this is fine for small amounts of data (a few 10'sK), if your images are large that ends up being a lot of memory reallocations as the result grows, I'd modify that code (or find another) that sets the required result length then fills it in.

Comment: If u just need some sample data you can use this site http://www.scalora.org/projects/uriencoder/ to encode images for inline image data URI's

Comment: `std::string` can hold NUL values, if you are having issues then it might be because of the way you are processing it.